# Loading JSON, HTML, XML, or Text into PETL from memory rather than file

Tags: python-3.x, file, memory, petl

The [PETL documentation](https://petl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/io.html) states that in order to load [JSON](https://petl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/io.html#json-files), [HTML](https://petl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/io.html#html-files), [XML](https://petl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/io.html#xml-files), or [text](https://petl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/io.html#text-files) the data can only originate from a file. How can I load data into PETL in any of these formats from memory such as a string variable rather than a file?

This would be useful when loading data that has already been cleansed or generated by upstream code. Writing to file only to re-read the file is a wasteful and risky (race conditions etc) operation.

Answer (score 0):

The following feels a little hacky but at least it avoids writing anything to disk.

```
import petl
from io import StringIO


d = '''<table>
        <tr>
            <td>foo</td><td>bar</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>a</td><td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>b</td><td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>c</td><td>2</td>
        </tr>
    </table>'''


class OpenableString():

    def __init__(self, str):
        self.value = StringIO(str)

    def open(self, mode):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        pass

    def __enter__(self):
        return self.value


os = OpenableString(d)

table1 = petl.fromxml(os, 'tr', 'td')

print(table1)
```

Output:

```
+-----+-----+
| foo | bar |
+=====+=====+
| a   | 1   |
+-----+-----+
| b   | 2   |
+-----+-----+
| c   | 2   |
+-----+-----+
```